# Dealing with Structs in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Suppose `struct_name` is the name of a struct I've defined, and array is a member in the struct defined as `char array[o]`

what does the following line produce? `(*struct_name).array`
an address location?

Comment: array[o] is some sort of hack...

Comment: maybe but's that's an awfully useful one :)

Comment: It that really array[o] or did you mean array[0]?  (i.e. zero, rather than an identifier 'letter-oh').  If the latter 'o' is a really poor name for an identifier.  Also rather than describe the code "Suppose...", why not just post the code directly, so we need not 'suppose' anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes (assuming struct_name is a pointer to your struct, otherwise the dereferencing just doesn't make sense)

btw, why not do struct_name->array ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've defined `struct_name` as an instance of your struct like this:

```
struct your_struct struct_name;
```

You want `struct_name.array` which, yes, produces an address to the `array` member. If you've defined `struct_name` as an instance of your struct like this:

```
struct your_struct *struct_name;
struct_name = malloc(sizeof(struct your_struct));
```

You want `struct_name->array`, which also returns the address of `array`.

If you've defined `struct_name` as the name of the struct itself like this:

```
typedef struct _struct_name {
    char array[5];
} struct_name;
```

Then you don't know what you want.